# How many regulars do the primorials 223092870 and 6469693230 have?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, divisibility, prime-factorization, primorial

Regulars = Divisors + Semidivisors

http://global.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/496213/regular-number

So for example:

- 6 has 5 regulars: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6.
- 8 has 4 regulars: 1, 2, 4, 8.
- 9 has 3 regulars: 1, 3, 9.
- 10 has 6 regulars: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10.
- 12 has 8 regulars: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12.
- A prime number has 2 regulars: 1 and itself.

I've already found the quantity of regulars of every primorial less than 223092870:

- 2 has 2 regulars
- 6 has 5 regulars
- 30 has 18 regulars
- 210 has 68 regulars
- 2310 has 283 regulars
- 30030 has 1161 regulars
- 510510 has 4843 regulars
- 9699690 has 19985 regulars

(Maybe there are a few mistakes, so if someone could also check the 4 last ones just to be sure it would be very nice of you.)

Once I get the quantity of regulars of 223092870 and 6469693230 I will finally be able to discover the secret of primorials (or maybe not). And I shall share this secret with the person who finds me the quantity of regulars of these two primorials =)

Comment: What is a semidivisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

23# : 83074

29# : 349670

31# : 1456458

37# : 6107257

41# : 25547835

43# : 106115655

Edit: I don't have the required 50 rep to comment, so I have to do comment on gammatester's answer from here:
Did you use 32-bit integers to bruteforce it? That could have lead to negative numbers and more solutions than there really are.
Also your $k_i$'s shouldn't be bounded by $\alpha_i$, should they?

Comment: No, I used 64-bit integers. Regarding the bounds for $k_i:$ What do you suggest, or better, what is your definition of regular. The Britannica link is not useful and I do not want to subscribe.

Comment: well, no bounds would make it correct as I see it.
As I understand it, a number M<=N is a regular divisor of N if all primes p that divide M divide N. Not sure why you have the same results for small values and different ones for big values ...

Comment: You are right, I updated my post.

Comment: We still differ by alot. I have the same values as Omega Force , so I guess my code is right.

Comment: After switching from Knuth's tuple enumeration algorithm to a much faster
recursive ad doc implementation (total time for all primorials up to 47# in less than 2 sec) I can reproduce your values and 
add another for 47# which is the largest primorial with 64 bit or less:
`47# = 614889782588491410    RegCnt(x) = 440396221`